# What is the meaning of "Counter-productive at best"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I cannot understand the last sentence of the following paragraph:

> Highly Emotional – While emotional expression is healthy and natural, with Campaigners even viewing it as a core part of their identity, it can come out strongly enough to cause problems for this personality type. Particularly when under stress, criticism or conflict, Campaigners can experience emotional bursts that are *counter-productive at best*.

Is it the same as *very counter-productive*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'At best' is used here to say that, for campaigners, there are a range of possible outcomes, none good, from an 'emotional burst', and that being counterproductive is the least bad one. If you have an electric shock, you will be startled and surprised **at best**. Less good outcomes could be that you are slightly injured, badly injured, or, **at worst**, killed.

> You use at best to indicate that even if you describe something as
>   favourably as possible or if it performs as well as it possibly can,
>   it is still not very good.
>
> *This policy, they say, is at best confused and at worst non-existent.
>
>   At best they were effective as antidepressants for no more than four months.*

[At best (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-best)